# How to shuffle matrix data in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix `M` of float values, how to shuffle `M` line-wise?

Comment: This sort of question is probably more suited for [Stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), as there is no statistics involved. I answered two of them because the answers were short, but please send more of these type of questions over there. Better yet: read the introduction to R, which holds the answer to at least your previous question...

Comment: Thank you! I thought R questions fit here, there must many more R pros here than at StackOverflow.com

Comment: Gorodetski you'd be surprised at the number of R pros on stack overflow-- I often get more responses to programming oriented R questions there than here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

something like:

```
nr<-dim(M)[1]
M[sample.int(nr),]
```

Comment: A bit shorter version: `M[sample.int(nrow(M)),]`